How can I measure the size of a Bison grammar?
I have a bison grammar in a ".y" file and I would like to know how big it is. Is there a way to get the number of items in the itemset? It's essentially the number of unique positions inside the grammar:
 X: • a b c
 X: a • b c
 X: a b • c
 X: a b c •

Using bison --report=states will say the number of states in the automaton, but that doesn't measure the size of the grammar itself. I also tried bison --report=itemsets but it looks like it only adds itemset information to each state in the report, without counting the itemsets themselves.
I hope I don't have to do this by hand (use text munging to strip semantic actions and punctuation from the file, and count how many "words" are left)

Isn't the number of unique positions inside the grammar the same as number of states? "They're the same picture."

They would be the same in the non-deterministic LR automaton, but bison uses the deterministic LR automaton. Each bison state stands for a set of positions, and some positions may appear in more than one state.
